# How to force Windows to authenticate a particular domain in the Domain\UserName format

Tags: windows, authentication, iis, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint setup in DomainA
Due to some organization preference we have to rename the domain to DomainB.
So in a test environment we changed the domain name from DomainA to DomainB(using rendom).
SharePoint applications are set to use Windows Authentication.
The application seems to be working fine but now it authenticates username with any domain prefix.
By domain prefix I mean the domain name part in DomainName\UserName.
So we checked our current production setup in DomainA and the behaviour is the same as in the test environment.
I could be wrong but I dont believe this is a SharePoint problem because the same is happening with my MSSQL also.
If I create any domain user locally and set the same password, running ssms as that user enables me to view/query my MSSQL server(Using Windows Authentication).
Is there a way to restrict this to one domain name ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it needs more planning and testing. I would test the changes first in a test environment and then move on to production.
You should change all accounts of your Application pool, service, IIS server, SQL Server etc, and consider search crawling, users

See these below links, should help you to plan.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sushrao/archive/2011/12/02/sharepoint-migrating-sharepoint-server-from-one-domain-to-another.aspx

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f484870-609e-4154-af59-fc940e643159/change-of-domain-name-of-the-sharepoint-groups?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

http://calvinirwin.net/2013/10/17/changing-sharepoint-site-domain-name/

Comment: I have gone through these links. But they dont solve my problem since the users are able to use SharePoint but I want to force the user to use DomainB\UserName but in my current situation it works with AnyDomain\UserName.